# custom counter and cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I created a custom counter 'rtaskno' and a command '\rtask' as following:

```
\newcounter{rtaskno}
\newcommand{\rtask}{%
   \stepcounter{rtaskno}%
   \thertaskno}
```

I like to use them as following:

```
\section{Task \rtask. Blah Blah..}

\section{Task \rtask. Blah Blah..}

\section{Task \rtask. Blah Blah..}

\section{Task \rtask. Blah Blah..}
```

Later in the text, if I want to cross-reference 'Task 3', how can I do it? Where to put label?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are tricky timing issues in your problem. If you are going to prepare a table of contents the thing as it is now will bomb out.

Probably the best thing to do is to use a two-pass strategy:

```
\newcounter{rtaskno}
\newcommand{\rtask}[1]{\refstepcounter{rtaskno}\label{#1}}
```

When you want to use the task number in your section titles you'll write

```
\rtask{label}
\section{Task \ref{label}. Blah}
```

Comment: When I am using this new command inside an amsmath's align environment the label is attached to the number of align's equation rather than the number of the new counter (showing it using `\ref` I get the number from align's counter). Is there a way to attach the label to the new counter even inside such an environment, correcting this behaviour?

Answer (score 29):

You will need to use `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter` to make your counter "visible" to the referencing mechanism. The label can go anywhere after the `\refstepcounter` as long as it's before the next `\refstepcounter` (for example the next theorem environment, section heading etc...

Using it *inside* a section heading might be tricky.

Answer (score 10):

There are two things that deserve attention: 1) you need to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`, and 2) since you are going to use `\rtask` inside a sectionning command you will have to protect it, or even better, declare it as robust from the beginning. I also included an argument of the definition, so that you can have the necessary label for cross-references:

EDIT: this approach will fail miserably if a table of contents is created. A possible workaround would be to use the optional argument for `\section`, but I don't like this option so much. For a proper possible solution when a ToC is created, see egreg's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{rtaskno}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rtask}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{rtaskno}%
   \thertaskno\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Task \rtask{task:one}. Blah Blah..}

\section{Task \rtask{task:two}. Blah Blah..}

\section{Task \rtask{task:three}. Blah Blah..}

\section{Task \rtask{task:four}. Blah Blah..}

Task~\ref{task:four}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to write the table of contents? My initial idea was the same as yours, but clearly it doesn't work.

Comment: @egreg: jeje... you're right. I din't test it with a ToC. Will delete this answer shortly.

Comment: please do not delete, when the ToC is not needed, your solution might work good enough for someone.

Comment: @Chang: I won't delete it, but I added an EDIT with a warning concerning the misbehaviour if a table of contents is created.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a new command for this:

```
\newcommand{\newTask}[2]{\section{Task \rtask. #2}\label{#1}}
```

and use it as such:

```
\newTask{t:first}{Blah Blah..}
\newTask{t:second}{Blah Blah..}
\newTask{t:third}{Blah Blah..}
```

Comment: That is not going to work. This will use the value of the section counter rather than the value of the section.