# Working with labels

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm not quite sure what the problem is, so I'll just post a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\twolabels[2]
{
    \label{my:#1}
    \label{my:#2}
}

\begin{document}
\twolabels{4}{a}
I have two labels: \ref{my:4} and \ref{my:a}.
\end{document}
```

Instead of referring me to 1 and 2, it gives me two ??'s. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The MWE works for me. Are you sure you compiled enough times? It takes at least two times for the changes in the labels to come trough. Also your MWE won't do anything good, since there is nothing to reference to (see @lockstep's answer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom counter and cross-referencing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21300/custom-counter-and-cross-referencing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In its minimal or default form, `\label`s only store the counter and the page that it's on, the former retrievable via `\ref` and the latter retrievable via `\pageref`.  TeX `\label`-`\ref` systems is used to *mark* the last referencable *counter* and store it in the `\label`. If there is no counter that was last referenced (as in your case), there will be no appropriate `\ref`, hence your `??` as output.

As a brief introduction to how one can use counter referencing, here is a way to achieve your result. First you define a counter using

```
\newcounter{mycount}
```

Then, whenever you want to store the counter for referencing, you perform

```
\refstepcounter{mycount}
```

This does two things: increases the counter by 1 (or "step" it), and adds a "referencing" capability or mark. Now, if you use `\label` it will store the value of `mycount` as well as the page that `mycount` was last `\refstep`-ped. Here's a minimal example of how that could work in your instance:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand\twolabels[2]
{
  \refstepcounter{mycount}\label{my:#1}%
  \refstepcounter{mycount}\label{my:#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\twolabels{4}{a}
I have two labels: \ref{my:4} and \ref{my:a}.
\end{document}
```

Now, this doesn't mean that you always have to create your own counter if you want to refernece something via `\label`-`\ref`. Instead, there are other counters that is `\refstep`-ped like `section` whenever you perform `\section`. Using the example above, if you had just placed `\label{test}` after the `\section` and subsequently used `\ref{test}`, you retrieve the section number `1` in the text.

Finally, you can also modify the way the counter is displayed in the text. For example, if you're interested in (lower case) Roman numerals for your counter, you could add

```
\renewcommand{\themycount}{\roman{mycount}}
```

after defining the counter `mycount`.

You need to compile twice for the references to be accurate, since information is first stored in an `.aux` file and retrieved upon the second compile.

Comment: FWIW: I had a similar problem and this answer is a bit over the top for me. Basically, I wanted to count citations used in a table, so I did basically: \refstepcounter{usedcitations}\label{usedcitationslabel} on every table entry and then anywhere in the document: \getrefnumber{usedcitationslabel}. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

The `\label`/`\ref` mechanism needs a counter that can be referred to. If you add, e.g., a `\section` command immediately after `\begin{document}`, your `\twolabels` macro will create references to section 1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\twolabels[2]
{
    \label{my:#1}
    \label{my:#2}
}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\twolabels{4}{a}
I have two labels: \ref{my:4} and \ref{my:a}.
\end{document}
```