# Customise my own subsubsection numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to write a thesis and would like to number the subsubsection titles within a section easily so I can refer to them nicely and easily later on in the document.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}
\usepackage[width=5.5in, height=8in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Exact Solutions of the Navier-Stokes Equations}

Intro.

\subsubsection{Solution 1: Description}

Solution 1

\subsubsection{Solution 2: Description}

Solution 2

\subsubsection{Solution 3: Description}

Solution 3

\end{document}
```

and the output comes out as:

1.0.1 Solution 1: Description

Solution 1

1.0.2 Solution 2: Description

Solution 2

but what I'd like is to have it appear as:

Solution 1: Description

Solution 1

Solution 2: Description

Solution 2

such that the part "Solution i" becomes the number - if that makes sense.

The reason I want to do this is so that: 1 - it looks nice, and 2 - so that I can use a \label and \ref later on so I can refer back to them later on in the document.

Comment: You're omitting the `subsection`  level --this is not recommended

Comment: The reason I am using subsubsections is because I do not want large titles (I suppose I may be able to edit this individually for these specific subsections), however, I think the question still stands, then for subsections.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21300/custom-counter-and-cross-referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that 'automatically' redefines the subsubsection header number format and numbering and restores it with the next `\section`.

I also used `\cleveref` so refer to the subsubsection as a Solution and not as a subsubsection.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[width=5.5in, height=8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\let\latexthesubsubsection\thesubsubsection
\let\latex@@seccntformat\@seccntformat

\newcommand{\othersubsubformat}{%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{Solution \arabic{subsubsection}}
  \def\@seccntformat##1{\csname the##1\endcsname:\ }
}
\newcommand{\restoresubsubformat}{%
\let\@seccntformat\latex@@seccntformat
\let\thesubsubsection\latexthesubsubsection
}

\xpretocmd{\section}{\restoresubsubformat}{}{}

\begin{document}



\section{Exact Solutions of the Navier-Stokes Equations}



\othersubsubformat

Intro.

We have a nice solution in \ref{solution:3}

\subsubsection{Description}

Solution 1

\subsubsection{Description}

Solution 2

\subsubsection{Description} \label[Solution]{solution:3}

Solution 3


\section{Other stuff}

\subsection{Foo}
\subsubsection{Foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.  In order to then continue to have subsubsections in a later section, how would I go about resetting the numbering?

Comment: @DanielWard: See the update please

Comment: Thank you again for your help, this works very well, except when I put it into my main document it messes up the table of contents.  This may be a seperate question but how do I go about making sure the table of contents is also changed appropriately?

Comment: Of course it messes up the ToC --> actually, a `theorem` like approach would be much better

Comment: That's not a bad idea, thank you I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found using Christian Hupfer's suggestion in one of his comments.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[width=5.5in, height=8in]{geometry}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\section{Exact Solutions of the Navier-Stokes Equations}


Intro.

See solution \ref{solution:3} for ...

\begin{solution} \textbf{Description} \\

Solution 1

\end{solution}

\begin{solution} \textbf{Description} \\

    Solution 2

\end{solution}

\begin{solution} \textbf{Description} \\ \label{solution:3}

    Solution 3

\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, unaccepting the solution, grabbing a comment by someone else and using this as self-answer and self-acceptance, this is not really kosher!

Comment: My bad, I didn't realise.  I mentioned you in the answer, I thought this would be okay.  I can re-accept your answer if you like.  It was just that this was the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

There are two *different* ways of suppressing subsubsection numbers:

1. Use `\subsubsection*`. This suppresses numbering completely and also supresses the addition of this subsubsection to the table of contents.
2. `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` (you only need this command once, best in the preamble of the document). This supresses the the printing of the numbers for subsubsection. It does not influence the table of contents generation.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are concerned about is that the font for subsections is too large for your liking then change the definition of the subsection font. You can find the (sub)subsection code via `texdoc article`. In your preamble do

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsection}{...} % changing the font specification 
\makeatother
```

and then use `\subsection{...}` instead of `\subsubsection{...}`  in your document.