# Labelling a custom counter inside align env

Tags: align, counters

I created a new counter and new commands to label and refer to this counter (the latter looks redundant here because I stripped away some formatting I have in it) according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21305/160156).

As the title says, when I'm trying to use my new counter inside an amsmath's align environment - it doesn't work. When `\nonumber` is added at the end of the relevant line - no label is created whatsoever (I checked the .aux file). When this is not added (as in the code below) the labeled counter is align's one rather than my custom counter, although mine was the last counter that was incremented (as it is `\refstepcounter`-ed right before the `\label` inside the new command).

How can I label my counter as opposed to align's one while inside this environment?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%equations' placeholders to allow breaking them in the middle and picking up from the same spot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21305/160156
\newcounter{eqplaceholdercounter}
\newcommand{\eqplaceholder}{\stepcounter{eqplaceholdercounter}\theeqplaceholdercounter}
\newcommand{\eqplaceholderlbl}[1]{{\refstepcounter{eqplaceholdercounter}\label{#1}\theeqplaceholdercounter}}
\newcommand{\eqplaceholderref}[1]{\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        eq1 \\
        eq2 \\
        eq3\quad \eqplaceholderlbl{plc:label} %\nonumber
    \end{align}

    But the ref is \eqplaceholderref{plc:label} instead of \theeqplaceholdercounter.
    While if I label outside of the align environment, like here: 
\eqplaceholderlbl{plc:label2}, all is well and I can reference it and get the correct number - \eqplaceholderref{plc:label2}.
\end{document}
```

The above code's output, as it is:

[image: The above code's output]

The above code's output, after uncommenting the `\nonumber`:

[image: The above code's output after uncommenting the nonumber command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This results from `align` capturing `\label` for use at a later stage within the processing cycle. If you want an immediate use of `\label` that coincides with your `\refstepcounter`, use `\ltx@label` (saved as the traditional `\label` within `align`-and-friends):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%equations' placeholders to allow breaking them in the middle and picking up from the same spot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21305/5764
\makeatletter
\newcounter{eqplaceholdercounter}
\newcommand{\eqplaceholder}{\stepcounter{eqplaceholdercounter}\theeqplaceholdercounter}
\newcommand{\eqplaceholderlbl}[1]{{\refstepcounter{eqplaceholdercounter}\ltx@label{#1}\theeqplaceholdercounter}}
\newcommand{\eqplaceholderref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  eq1 \\
  eq2 \\
  eq3\quad \eqplaceholderlbl{plc:label} %\nonumber
\end{align}

But the ref is \eqplaceholderref{plc:label} instead of \theeqplaceholdercounter.
While if I label outside of the align environment, like here: 
\eqplaceholderlbl{plc:label2}, all is well and I can reference it and get the correct number - \eqplaceholderref{plc:label2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! I also wanted to add a remark to make people notice the important lines in your code - `\makeatletter` before the `\newcommand` (that uses @ as a letter) and its opposite `\makeatother` after it, just in case.

Comment: @et_l: Indeed. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) You can also make things a bit cleaner and define `\makeatletter \newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label} \makeatother`, allowing you to use `\ltxlabel` within your main document.